# WPF: How to dynamically update FontSize when the FontSize of the Windows changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, attached-properties

I found the mistake, thus here the code for whom is interested in scaling text.

First the ValueConverter and the MarkupExtension that is necessary to be able to pass a double as parameter.

```
public class ScaleValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double v = (double) value * (double) parameter;
        return v;
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public sealed class DoubleExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public DoubleExtension (double value) { this.Value = value; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public override Object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider sp) { return Value; }
};
```

And now the XAML:

```
<TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top"
  FontSize="{Binding Path=FontSize, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
      Converter={StaticResource ScaleValueConverter},
  ConverterParameter={local:Int32 2}}"
>Some Text</TextBlock>
```

This way it is possible to scale all fonts by just adjusting the Window's FontSize. All other font sizes are relative and will depend on it.

Comment: An alternative would be a ScaleTransform, assigned to the TextBlock's LayoutTransform property.

Comment: I switched of Cleartype by TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display". Using ScaleTransform makes the font look ugly again, similar to the Ideal TextFormarttingMode.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. Binding a TextBlock's FontSize like you did works fine for me, with a converter that returns a double value. How does your converter look like?